# Coworker touched me inappropriately - How can I get her fired for this?

Tags: ethics

My coworker, who is a female, walked up to me in passing, and touched my right breast with her pen, and I shoved her. On her way back, she did the same, and touched my right breast with her pen, and I shoved her again.

This was happening as I was teaching a Pilates class. So angry I want her gone.

---

**Question** (based on the OP's comment below):

How can I get her fired for this?  I don’t want to lose my job.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace Diane. Please take the [tour] and read the [help/dont-ask] to familiarize yourself with this site. There you will find that the question you posted is unanswerable, as it lacks a question for starters, an actionable goal, etc. Please fix this if you want us to help you

Comment: How can I get her fired for this? don’t want to lose my job

Comment: Depends on your jurisdiction. In (most of) the US, you can be fired for this. But then you can also be fired because your boss didn't like the colour of your blouse today, so...

Comment: Are there witnesses to what happened? It would make the whole thing way easier for you to handle (so it doesn't end up as just your word against hers)

Comment: I think it’s on the camera system they have in the studio. I’m contemplating asking for a meeting with the owner. Not sure why I’m so afraid….i hate confrontations.

Answer (score 3):

You go to your supervisor / manager, and explain what happened.  If they don't respond appropriately, inform them that you are calling the police to report sexual assault, because that's exactly what this was.

If you wish, you can call the police anyway, as you don't need "permission" from your boss to report a crime.

If your gym is a franchise, call their corporate office and ask to speak to their HR department, and report your coworker there as well.  Most companies have policies and procedures in place that have to be followed to protect them and thus you.  When I was in management, I had to have a "response plan" in the desk ready to go as a requirement.  Not sure if your company is like that or not.

Comment: Thank you. Great advise I just got braver.

Answer (score 2):

Obligatory 'Not a Lawyer' - but doing something twice, even if it's using an Object I'm fairly certain that's Sexual Assault (admittedly doing it only once would also be SA - but it could be an accident or construed as an accident).

That means a Crime *based on your description of the events* appears to have been committed.

Your options:

- Engage with your local advocacy groups and ask them for help in going to the...
- Police. If there's video and witness evidence, they might decide to press charges.
- You could also engage with your local advocacy groups with advice in how to raise the issue with HR
- If your company is small and there's no formal HR department - simply go to the Owner, ask them to review the evidence, point to whatever part of your contract or local law was breached and take it from there.

Comment: It is a large franchise. I will ask for a meeting with the owner to just get her gone. Thank you for your time and advise. Much appreciated.